# How to use .htaccess to remove ?fontstyle=f-smaller at the end of an URL?

Tags: .htaccess

the template I am using is generating links with ?fontstyle=f-smaller or ?fontstyle=f-smaller at the end of the URL (according to the user's text size preferences). Now this is causing obvious duplicate content issues. I have disabled the feature but the URLs are still being served.

I would like to use .htaccess to strip these off my URLs. For example:
http://www.mysite.com/article?fontstyle=f-smaller
would redirect to
http://www.mysite.com/article

I have searched here and elsewhere about it but I only found how to remove segments. The change I want being *within* a segment, I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(^|&)fontstyle=f-smaller(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [R=301,L]
```